# Insert date and time in formats mm/dd/yyyy and time in the format hh24:mm:ss in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

Lets say I have a table Student with columns Name,DOJ,TOJ.
Inorder to enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format and timestamp in the format hh24:mm:ss I used ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY' and ALTER NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='HH24:MI:SS' but i want to know an alternative solution to enter in this format  without involving session. Please guide me through this.

[CLICK HERE TO VIEW COLUMNS AND THEIR DATA TYPES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBijB.png)

Comment: Oracles doesn't have a `time` data type so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I meant timestamp now the question has been edited

Comment: In order to solve “this”? Did you explain what “this” is?

Comment: A `date` column has no format, any format you see is applied by the application _displaying_ that date value

Comment: Please don't link to images. Paste the table as text into your request instead. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

We store dates/times either in a `DATE` column (which is Oracle's inappropriate name for a datetime) or a `TIMESTAMP` column (which has more precision and can handle timezones, too). These types have no format. This is important, because thus comparing and sorting them in the database works fine, because the DBMS knows how to handle datetimes, while the users see the date in their format. I, for instance, have set my Windows to German, so I will see the datetimes in some German format, while you will see the same date in a format you are used to.

There are few situations where you want to store date and time separately. The reason is typically that you can set them null. A date without a time means "the whole day". A time without a date means "every day this time". But then you often want this even more advanced anyway ("every Tuesday and Wednesday", "every December 24", etc.) for which you need soemthing more sophisticated then just date and time split into two.

So, usually we just store date and time combined. For a precision down to seconds we use `DATE`. If we wanted them separately we'd have to think of an appropriate data type, because Oracle has no real date type and no time type either. So we'd either use `DATE` and ignore the date part or the time part or we use strings. The former solution is usually preferred, because you cannot mistakenly enter invalid data like February 30 or 23:66:00.

If you want to store *formatted* dates and times, you are talking about strings. I don't recommend this. Strings are not the appropriate data types for dates and times. And a format '01/02/2000' is ambiguous. Some people will read this as February 1, others as January 2.

If you wanted to do this, you would have to change the column types to `VARCHAR2` and simply store values like '02/25/2021' and '13:28:56'.

But if you wanted to sort your data or compare dates/times then or just show them to a foreign user in a format they are used to, you would always have to convert them. E.g.:

```
select *
from mytable
order by to_date(doj || ' ' || toj, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that to change default format you have no other option but to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT either in database level or session level.

But If your purpose is to show the date in a specific format in the front end then you can use to_char() function as below:

```
SELECT NAME, to_CHAR(DOJ,'dd/mm/yyyy'),to_CHAR(TOJ,'HH24:MI:SS') FROM table
```

To change the default date format in system level:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY' scope=both;
```

You can also change the default date format at startup time with a login trigger to change the **nls_date_format**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_DATE_FORMAT
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
call DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_DATE_FORMAT','YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: How to change it in database level

Comment: You can't do that. When you set NLS_DATE_FORMAT at database level then you just define the **default** value for the session level parameter, but on session level it can be anything else.